# Router Zyxel EX3301-T0 static IP address for wired device

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, static-ip

I did assign a static IP address 192.168.1.3 for a device, with a known MAC address,
which was connected by wire to the router.
That was done via "Home networking" → "Static DHCP".
However, in the page "System" → "ARP Table", the MAC address was bound to a
different IP address. So the static binding did not work.

I also tried to reboot the router, and the device, and even tried to decrease the DHCP
lease time to 2 minutes. But nothing of that helped. The device persistently got the same
IP address, and not the one I had defined.

Interesting though, is that static IP addresses for **wireless** devices work!

Do you know a solution to this problem with wired devices?

Comment: Does the device actually use DHCP to obtain its address in the first place? (Have you tried restarting it or otherwise directly forcing it to renew its lease?) Keep in mind the ARP table is _not_ the same thing as the DHCP lease table, and, also, it maps IP addresses to MAC addresses (not MACs to IPs!) so it's perfectly normal to have both the new IP and the old IP mapped to the same MAC.

Comment: Thank you for info.
* Don't know if the device actually uses DHCP. Will try to find out.
* I have tried restarting the device.

Comment: To find out – check the router's DHCP lease table, it _should_ have one (listing all active DHCP devices). If it doesn't have one, install Wireshark on a PC on the same network (preferably wired), start a capture, restart the device and see if it broadcasts any DHCPDISCOVERs (display filter `bootp` or `eth.src = aa:bb:…`) may help). And if it doesn't use DHCP to obtain its address, there's nothing you can do from outside to force it to use a different one...

Comment: Thanks again. Now it's time for real work...